# creating nested dictionary from the values automatically in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a array and i am trying to created a nested dictionary using script which will automatically update dictionary based on array values

```
string[,] items = new string[8, 3] { 
    { "blue", "one","available" },
    { "blue", "two","available" },
    { "blue", "three","not available" },
    { "black", "six", "not available"},
    { "black", "four","available" },
    { "brown", "one","available" },
    { "brown", "seven","available" },
    { "brown", "six","not available" }
};
```

So I am expecting output like this

```
[{
    "blue": {
        "one": {
            "available": ["store1 ", "store2 "]
        },
        "two": {
            "available": ["store1 ", "store2 "]
        },
        "three": {
            "not available": ["store1 ", "store2 "]
        }

    }

}, {
    "black": {
        "three": {
            "not available": ["store1 ", "store2 "]
        },
        "six": {
            "available": ["store1 ", "store2 "]
        },
        "four": {
            "not available": ["store1 ", "store2 "]
        }
    }
}, {
    "brown": {
        "one": {
            "available": ["store1 ", "store2 "]
        },
        "seven": {
            "availble": ["store1 ", "store2 "]
        },
        "size": {
            "not available": ["store1 ", "store2 "]
        }

    }
}]
```

I am new to c# how could create a nested dictionary in above format?

Comment: It's not clear to me how your input relates to your output. Where does the black/three combination come from? Where do store1 and store2 come from? Please explain what your data is meant to represent.

Comment: for that we have to loop through this string[,] items = new string[8, 3] { 
    { "blue", "one","available" },
    { "blue", "two","available" },
    { "blue", "three","not available" },
    { "black", "six", "not available"},
    { "black", "four","available" },
    { "brown", "one","available" },
    { "brown", "seven","available" },
    { "brown", "six","not available" }
};

Comment: "I am new to c#" Learn to crawl before you walk - loop through, determine if the outer key exists in the dictionary, add it if not. Determine if the intermediate key exists in the outer dictionary, add it if not, and add the value to the inner collection.  Sure, someone will post a slick one-line Linq answer, but does that really _teach_ you anything?

Comment: Your comment really hasn't answered my question - there's no black/three combination in your sample data, nor a brown/size combination. Have you just been sloppy writing out your expected output? And again, where do "store1" and "store2" come from?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the question might be asking how to add those, store1 and store2 to the original array.

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm: I don't think so - I think it's "convert from form X to form Y" but the sample data in form Y doesn't appear to exist in form X...

Answer (score 0):

`[store1,store2]` as default values for every element:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>> dictionaryLevel0 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>>();

string[,] items = new string[8, 3]
{
    {"blue", "one", "available"}, {"blue", "two", "available"},
    {"blue", "three", "not available"}, {"black", "six", "not available"}, {"black", "four", "available"}, {"brown", "one", "available"}, {"brown", "seven", "available"},
    {"brown", "six", "not available"}
};

for (int i = 0; i <= items.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    if(!dictionaryLevel0.ContainsKey(items[i, 0]))
        dictionaryLevel0.Add(items[i, 0], new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>());

    var dictionaryLevel1 = dictionaryLevel0[items[i, 0]];

    if (!dictionaryLevel1.ContainsKey(items[i, 1]))
        dictionaryLevel1.Add(items[i, 1], new Dictionary<string, List<string>>());

    var dictionaryLevel2 = dictionaryLevel1[items[i, 1]];

    if (!dictionaryLevel2.ContainsKey(items[i, 2]))
        dictionaryLevel2.Add(items[i, 2], new List<string> { "store1", "store2"});
}
```